# The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use **Class Based Views** for my Django project.
I made a simple form where the admin is able to add new data using the CreateView. 
The data is successfully added but the image isn't getting uploaded after the form submission the user is redirected to the another page.
Thus as I load my home page an error is generated, which I'm not able to find the solution to.

**Trace back error**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/

Django Version: 1.11.21
Python Version: 2.7.16
Installed Applications:
['projectfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\Maala\MaalaWeddings\projectfiles\templates\projectfiles\HomePage.html, error at line 16
   The 'food_pic' attribute has no file associated with it.   6 : 
   7 : {% block asd %}
   8 : 
   9 : <div class='box' align='right'>
   10 : Food<hr>
   11 : {% if food_count %}
   12 : {% for i in food_data %}
   13 :     {{ i.item_name }}
   14 :     Rs.{{ i.item_price }}
   15 :     if
   16 :     <img src="{{ i.food_pic }}" alt=' {{ i.food_pic.url }} ' width="124" height="124"/>
   17 :     <img>
   18 : {% endfor %}
   19 : {% else %}
   20 : <h6>NO DATA</h6>
   21 : {% endif %}
   22 : </div>
   23 : 
   24 : 
   25 : <br>
   26 : <div class='box' align='right'>


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  63.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1040.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  708.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  849.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  890.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in url
  69.         self._require_file()

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in _require_file
  46.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /home/
Exception Value: The 'food_pic' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

**models.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date, datetime




class Food_Data(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_price = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    food_pic = models.ImageField( upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = ("Food Data")
        verbose_name = ("Food Data")
```

**forms.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .models import *
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import *



class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Food_Data
        fields = ("item_name","item_price","food_pic")
```

**home.html**

```html
<title>Home</title>
{% include 'projectfiles/base.html' %}

<br><br><br>
<h1 align='center'>TESTING</h1>

{% block asd %}

<div class='box' align='right'>
Food<hr>
{% if food_count %}
{% for i in food_data %}
    {{ i.item_name }}
    Rs.{{ i.item_price }}

    <img src="{{ i.food_pic }}" alt='{{ i.food_pic.url }}' width="124" height="124"/>
    <img>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h6>NO DATA</h6>
{% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock asd %}
```

**views.py**

```py
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "projectfiles\HomePage.html"

#Takes data from the Food database and renders it.
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #Food Model
        context['food_data'] = Food_Data.objects.all()
        context['food_count'] = Food_Data.objects.all().count

        return context




class Food_CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Food_Data
    form_class = FoodForm
    template_name = 'projectfiles\Create_food_View.html'
    # renamed it because of /f error

    def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('Add-Food')
```

I expect the page to render the newly entered data with the image.
if i comment out the img tag for the food item it loads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the related image found, then try to get the `url` attribute of it.

```
<title>Home</title>
{% include 'projectfiles/base.html' %}

<br><br><br>
<h1 align='center'>TESTING</h1>

{% block asd %}
<div class='box' align='right'>
Food<hr>
{% if food_count %}
{% for i in food_data %}
    {{ i.item_name }}
    Rs.{{ i.item_price }}
    {% if i.food_pic %}
        <img src="{{ i.food_pic }}" alt='{{ i.food_pic.url }}' width="124" height="124"/>
        <img>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h6>NO DATA</h6>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock asd %}
```

Comment: I want to show the item pictures to the user.
The Image isn't getting uploaded through the form. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza It can be for any reason, I don't have any clue about it. I need more details to guide you.

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza but the question title and reported error was related to the `{% if i.food_pic %}` and your answer is related to another problem!